# PHP - Converting SQL CE file to SQLITE is slow

Tags: php, sqlite

Good day!

I am having a problem in slow execution of my PHP script. I am not sure if this is valid question. Please bear with me.

My task is to create a web app to convert an existing SDF file(SQL Server CE) to a DB(SQlite file). I am using PHP.

The SQlite database will be used in a mobile application.

Here is the steps of my conversion:

1. The user can select single or multiple SDF file.
2. I will connnect first to that SDF File. I found a very helpful script. 
   [Read SQL Compact Edition (* .sdf) with PHP](http://www.klemmkeil.de/sql-compact-edition-sdf-mit-php-auslesen/)
3. I will create the SQLite database file and create the needed tables.
4. I would select the data from the SDF, and then insert the data to their respective tables in the SQLite database.

I would have to repeat this process if the user selected multiple files.

Here is my code for your reference:

```html
           /**
             * ARBalances
             */
            $file_db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ARBalances (
                    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    CustomerCode NVARCHAR(10),
                    BillingDate TEXT,
                    Balance DECIMAL(15,2),
                    SalesId NVARCHAR(30),
                    Amount DECIMAL(18,2),
                    Payment DECIMAL(18,2))");
          
          
          /**
             * Insert Data to db file. Select ARBalances from SDF file
             */
            $sdf->execute("SELECT * FROM ARBalances");

            $this->data_array = [
              'customer_code' => NULL,
              'billing_date' => NULL,
              'balance' => NULL,
              'sales_id' => NULL,
              'amount' => NULL,
              'payment' => NULL,
            ];

            $ar_balances = [];

            while (!$sdf->eof()) {

              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')] = $this->data_array;
              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['customer_code'] = $sdf->fieldvalue('CustomerCode');

              $date = str_replace('/', '-', $sdf->fieldvalue('BillingDate'));
              $date = new DateTime($date);
              $billing_date = strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
              $billing_date = (int)$billing_date * 1000;

              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['billing_date'] = $billing_date;
              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['balance'] = (float)$sdf->fieldvalue('Balance');
              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['sales_id'] = (string)$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId');
              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['amount'] = (float)$sdf->fieldvalue('Amount');
              $ar_balances[$sdf->fieldvalue('SalesId')]['payment'] = (float)$sdf->fieldvalue('Payment');

              $sdf->movenext();
            }

            $insert = "INSERT INTO ARBalances(CustomerCode, BillingDate, Balance, SalesId, Amount, Payment)
                      VALUES (:customer_code, :billing_date, :balance, :sales_id, :amount, :payment)";

            $stmt = $file_db->prepare($insert);

            $stmt->bindParam(':customer_code', $customer_code);
            $stmt->bindParam(':billing_date', $billing_date);
            $stmt->bindParam(':balance', $balance);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sales_id', $sales_id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $amount);
            $stmt->bindParam(':payment', $payment);

            foreach ($ar_balances as $value) {
              $customer_code = $value['customer_code'];
              $billing_date = $value['billing_date'];
              $balance = $value['balance'];
              $sales_id = $value['sales_id'];
              $amount = $value['amount'];
              $payment = $value['payment'];
              $stmt->execute();
            }
```

That code is for the **ARBalances** table only.I have 38 tables in the database. Some tables have 200+ records. My execution time takes 5 mins ust for a single conversion! I don't know if this is normal, but I think it takes too long.

I think the while loop is what causes this problem. To be honest I am not really familiar with computer science concepts or looping optimization.

Hope you can help me how to optimize my code. Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Hope I explained myself clearly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1. Drop `AUTOINCREMENT` from your primary key; it slows down inserts and [usually isn't needed](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). 2. Move the statement preparation outside of your loop and re-use the same one for all inserts.  3.  Put all the inserts into a single transaction. 4. Read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) for more.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Thanks for you suggestions. I have already applied no. 1. It improves a bit. I have also read the link you posted. I am trying to edit my code now, Just a quick question, how can I re-use a statemen preparation for all the the inserts?  I mean they have different column name and diferrent number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap your sqlite inserts as a transaction.  You can find more info at the following:
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-php/transaction/